# Array of TimeSeriesIds return error from Azure Time Series Insights Preview API

Tags: azure-timeseries-insights

We are trying to fetch values from the Azure Time Series Insights Preview API.

This request:

```
{
"getEvents": {
    "timeSeriesId": [
        "3 - 1179 - Temperatur"
    ],
    "searchSpan": {
        "from": "2019-07-02T06:00:00Z",
        "to": "2019-07-23T10:13:36.067Z"
    }
}
```

and this request:

```
{
    "getEvents": {
        "timeSeriesId": [
            "3 - 1175 - Temperatur"
        ],
        "searchSpan": {
            "from": "2019-07-02T06:00:00Z",
            "to": "2019-07-23T10:13:36.067Z"
        }
    }
}
```

Individually works fine, but when trying to combine them into a single request:

```
{
    "getEvents": {
        "timeSeriesId": [
            "3 - 1175 - Temperatur", "3 - 1179 - Temperatur"
        ],
        "searchSpan": {
            "from": "2019-07-02T06:00:00Z",
            "to": "2019-07-23T10:13:36.067Z"
        }
    }
}
```

We get this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidInput",
        "message": "Values in a single time series ID '[\"3 - 1175 - Temperatur\",\"3 - 1179 - Temperatur\"]' must match the time series ID properties '[SeriesId:String]' defined for the environment.",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "TimeSeriesIdValueMismatch"
        }
    }
}
```

From what I can see, it basically means that the TimeSeriesId's does not exist, but they work individually. From the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/preview-query) I can only understand that this should work?

Example query from doc:

```
    {
  "getEvents": {
    "timeSeriesId": ["PU.123","W00158","ABN.9890"],
    "timeSeriesName" : null,
    "searchSpan": {
        "from":  "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z",
        "to":  "2016-08-01T00:16:50Z"
    },
    "filter": { "tsx": "($event.Value.Double != null) OR ($event.Status.String = 'Good')"
    },
    "projectedProperties": [{"name":"Building","type":"String"}, {"name":"Temperature","type":"Double"}]
  }
 }
```

Comment: After reading the documentation a bit closer, I have realised that the TimeSeriesId can be put together by more than one field, and hence array as a value. There seems to be no way of asking for more than one event, or aggregate without specifying the TSI id in the preview API.